# What is unique about this?

Tags: prior-art-request, us9098730

In reference to the patent: [US9098730](https://www.google.com/patents/US9098730)

This patent is essentially for an external hard drive with FTK Imager on it. How can a patent be made for that? There is nothing on this drive that was used or created by UHY, Eric Shirk or anyone else. It is simply running a command line version of a patented tool already.

Additionally, this tool has nothing to do with persistent memory that it keeps alluding to in the thesis, it captures only active partitions on a powered on hard drive. This process is not accepted as a "forensic image" any way and could be challenged in court.